# Как сделать ссылку неактивной после нажатия?

Tags: html

Есть ссылка, при нажатии на которую нужно вывести блок информации и одновременно сделать ссылку неактивной (чтобы ее не было видно). Первый пункт я сделал, а сделать ссылку неактивной не выходит.

```html
<script>
var show;
function look(type)
{
param=document.getElementById(type);
if(param.style.display == "none")
{
if(show) show.style.display = "none";
param.style.display = "block";
show = param;
}
else param.style.display == "none";
}
</script>
<a onclick="look('additional')" href="#" >Подробнее</a>
   <ul style="display:none;" id="additional" class="populartags">
     <li class="additional"><a href="/www/test.html">Тест</a></li>
     <li class="additional"><a href="/www/test2.html">Тест2</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: e.preventdefault() есть такая штука которая делает ссылку кликабельной, но не активной, или через сss pointer-events: none;/* делаем ссылку некликабельной */

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужно задать оформление для ссылок псевдокласса `:visited` - http://htmlbook.ru/css/visited

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('additional').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
  
  var info = document.getElementById('additional-info');
  
  if (info.style.display === 'none') {
    info.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    info.style.display = 'none';
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<a id="additional" href="#" >Подробнее</a>

<ul id="additional-info" style="display: none;" class="populartags">
  <li><a href="/www/test.html">Тест</a></li>
  <li><a href="/www/test2.html">Тест2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Здесь это работает! Но что то в моем коде - не хочет. Пробовал в коде прописать - и подключать внешний скрипт :(

Comment: можете в JSBin ili JSFiddle скинуть весь код страницы? может `id` такая же есть еще одна или что-то в этом роде..

Answer (score 1):

А почему не просто: `<a href='#' onclick = '$(this).hide(); return false;'>Some link</a>` ?

---

Или:

```
<a href='#' onclick = '$(this).toggleClass('hidden'); return false;'>Some link</a>
```

css:

```
.hidden{display: none;}
```

---

Или вообще вот так:

```
<a href = '' onclick='showSome(this)' target ='additional'>Some description</a>
```

JS:

```
function showSome(obj){
    obj.style.display = 'none';
    var target = obj.getAttribute('target');
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}
```